# In the following code, Canvas layer disappears on mouse click in Fabric.js and Firefox stops responding when creating canvas to image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

http://jsfiddle.net/rodrigopandini/gj7HT/

I'm using this example to drag & drop images from my computer to canvas using Fabric.js.

```
//Drag and Drop Image
                        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
                        function handleDragStart(e) {
                            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                                img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                            });
                            this.classList.add('img_dragging');
                        }

                        function handleDragOver(e) {
                            if (e.preventDefault) {
                                e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                            }

                            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
                            // NOTE: comment above refers to the article (see top) -natchiketa

                            return false;
                        }

                        function handleDragEnter(e) {
                            // this / e.target is the current hover target.
                            this.classList.add('over');
                        }

                        function handleDragLeave(e) {
                            this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
                        }

                        function handleDrop(e) {
                            // this / e.target is current target element.

                            /*
                            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                                e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
                            }
                            */

                            e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
                            e.preventDefault(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.

                            // handle desktop images
                            if (e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {

                                var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                                    // Only process image files.
                                    if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
                                        // Read the File objects in this FileList.
                                        var reader = new FileReader();
                                        // listener for the onload event
                                        reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                            // create img element
                                            var img = document.createElement('img');
                                            img.src = evt.target.result;

                                            // put image on canvas
                                            var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                                                width: img.width,
                                                height: img.height,
                                                // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative to the canvas container.
                                                left: e.layerX,
                                                top: e.layerY
                                            });
                                            canvas.add(newImage);
                                        };
                                        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                                        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                                // handle browser images
                            else {
                                var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');
                                var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                                    width: img.width,
                                    height: img.height,
                                    // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative to the canvas container.
                                    left: e.layerX,
                                    top: e.layerY
                                });
                                canvas.add(newImage);
                            }

                            return false;
                        }

                        function handleDragEnd(e) {
                            // this/e.target is the source node.
                            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                                img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                            });
                        }

                        if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
                            // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

                            // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
                            var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
                            [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                                img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                                img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
                            });
                            // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
                            var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
                            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
                            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                            canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                            canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                        } else {
                            // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
                            alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
                        }
                        //End Drag and Drop
```

For adding multiple images by drag and drop I used the above code (jsfiddle example).
Here's my code which is working fine when I add images one by one on Canvas.

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id) };

                    //Upload Click 
                    var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
                        upload = document.getElementById("upload");

                    fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        if (upload) {
                            upload.click();
                        }
                        e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
                    }, false);
                    //End

                    function applyFilter(index, filter) {
                        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
                        obj.filters[index] = filter;
                        obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                    }

                    function applyFilterValue(index, prop, value) {
                        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
                        if (obj.filters[index]) {
                            obj.filters[index][prop] = value;
                            obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                        }
                    }

                    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),

                        f = fabric.Image.filters;

                    //Canvas Events
                    canvas.on({
                        'object:selected': function () {
                            fabric.util.toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))
                                .forEach(function (el) {
                                    el.disabled = false;
                                })

                            //Check for already applied filter on Image after selecting an image
                            var filters = ['grayscale', 'invert', 'remove-white', 'sepia', 'sepia2',
                                'brightness', 'noise', 'gradient-transparency', 'pixelate',
                                'blur', 'sharpen'];

                            for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                                $(filters[i]).checked = !!canvas.getActiveObject().filters[i];
                            }
                            canvas._activeObject.bringToFront();
                        },

                        //'selection:cleared': function() {
                        //        fabric.util.toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))
                        //            .forEach(function(el) { el.disabled = true; })                
                        //}                                        
                    });

                    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('upload');
                    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
                    var c = document.getElementById('c');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    //Canvas Handler
                    function handleImage(e) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (event) {
                            var img = new Image();
                            img.onload = function () {
                                canvas.width = img.width;
                                canvas.height = img.height;
                                context.drawImage(img);

                            }
                            img.src = event.target.result;                     
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
                    }

                    //Fabric.JS single image handler
                    document.getElementById('upload').onchange = function handleImage(e) {

                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function(event) {
                                var imgObj = new Image();
                                imgObj.src = event.target.result;
                                imgObj.onload = function() {
                                    var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                                    image.set({
                                        left: 250,
                                        top: 250,
                                        angle: 20,
                                        padding: 10,
                                        cornersize: 10,
                                    }).scale(0.4);
                                    canvas.add(image);
                                }
                            }
                            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);                            
                    }
                    //End

                    //Static Image in background
                    function setBackgrnd() {
                        fabric.Image.fromURL('/2-road.jpg', function (img) {
                            var oImg = img.set({ left: 400, top: 300, opactiy:0.5, selectable:false, lockHorizontally: false, lockVertically: false, lockScaling: false, lockRotation: false }).scale(1);
                            //oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.blur());
                            //oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                            //canvas.setBackgroundImage('/2-road.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                            canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                            canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                            canvas.sendToBack(oImg);
                            $('#delBackgrnd').click(function() {
                                canvas.getObjects();
                                remove(oImg);
                                canvas.renderAll();

                            });
                            //function setBackgrnd() {
                            //    canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                            //    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                            //}

                            //function delBackgrnd() {
                            //    fxRemove(oImg, canvas.renderAll());
                            //}

                        });
                    }

                    //Clears Everything on Canvas
                    function clearCanvas() {
                        canvas.clear();
                    }

                    //Delete Background Image
                    function delBackgrnd() {                    
                        //SelectedObject.onclick = function () {
                        //    if (canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
                        //        canvas.getActiveGroup().forEachObject(function (o) { canvas.remove(o) });
                        //        canvas.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();
                        //    } else {
                        //        canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
                        //    }
                        //};


                    }

                    //Generate Collage
                    function convertCanvasToImage() {
                        //var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
                        canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
                        var image_src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                        //document.write('<img src="' + image_src + '"/>');
                        window.open(image_src);
                    }

                    //Drag and Drop Image
                    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
                    function handleDragStart(e) {
                        [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                            img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                        });
                        this.classList.add('img_dragging');
                    }

                    function handleDragOver(e) {
                        if (e.preventDefault) {
                            e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                        }

                        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
                        // NOTE: comment above refers to the article (see top) -natchiketa

                        return false;
                    }

                    function handleDragEnter(e) {
                        // this / e.target is the current hover target.
                        this.classList.add('over');
                    }

                    function handleDragLeave(e) {
                        this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
                    }

                    function handleDrop(e) {
                        // this / e.target is current target element.

                        /*
                        if (e.stopPropagation) {
                            e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
                        }
                        */

                        e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
                        e.preventDefault(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.

                        // handle desktop images
                        if (e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {

                            var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                                // Only process image files.
                                if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
                                    // Read the File objects in this FileList.
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    // listener for the onload event
                                    reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                        // create img element
                                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                                        img.src = evt.target.result;

                                        // put image on canvas
                                        var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                                            width: img.width,
                                            height: img.height,
                                            // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative to the canvas container.
                                            left: e.layerX,
                                            top: e.layerY
                                        });
                                        canvas.add(newImage);
                                    };
                                    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            // handle browser images
                        else {
                            var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');
                            var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                                width: img.width,
                                height: img.height,
                                // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative to the canvas container.
                                left: e.layerX,
                                top: e.layerY
                            });
                            canvas.add(newImage);
                        }

                        return false;
                    }

                    function handleDragEnd(e) {
                        // this/e.target is the source node.
                        [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                            img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                        });
                    }

                    if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
                        // Browser supports HTML5 DnD.

                        // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
                        var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
                        [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                            img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                            img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
                        });
                        // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
                        var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
                        canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
                        canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                        canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                        canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                    } else {
                        // Replace with a fallback to a library solution.
                        alert("This browser doesn't support the HTML5 Drag and Drop API.");
                    }
                    //End Drag and Drop
//End of Code
```

My original HTML canvas tag is

```
<div id="canvas-container" class="canvas-container" >
 <canvas id="c" width="800" height="600" style="left: -300px; border: 1px dotted;"></canvas>                    
</div>
```

But, when I integrated this code the images are adding to the canvas but as I click on Canvas they disappears. I inspected element in Chrome and found that there are 2 Canvas tags.

```
<div id="canvas-container" class="canvas-container">
  <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
   <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
    <canvas id="c" width="800" height="600" style="left: 0px; border: 1px dotted; position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 600px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="lower-canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas class="upper-canvas" width="800" height="600" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
   </div>
   <canvas class="upper-canvas" width="800" height="600" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
 </div>                    
</div>
```

When I changed the position of all elements in above code to `position: relative;`, it works.
The 3 extra Canvas tags are generated automatically. How can I change the position? Also, when I generate the png or jpg image of canvas using DataURL, firefox stops responding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the css of that library, by using the following code.

```
/deep/ .canvas-container{

.upper-canvas {

position: relative !important;

 }
}
```